# Using Arcade to label, using coded values in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, domains, arcade

I am trying to label features that have coded domains in ArcGIS Pro. In ArcMap the procedure is to use the coded domains in an expression as shown below, but you have to enable the codes using the checkbox; as shown in the snippet below. In ArcGIS Pro this is Arcade driven and we are having issues coming up with a correct expression to achieve this.

How would I do this using Arcade in ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do in words as well.  That way any answer(s) to your question and your question itself will be available to future searches.

Comment: Trying to label features that have coded domains in ArcPro. In ArcMap the procedure is to use the coded domains in an expression shown, but you have to enable the codes using the check box; as shown in the snippet above. In ArcPro this is Arcade driven we were have issues coming up with a correct expression to achieve this.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are labelling a feature which has a Domain on the field then this appears to be automatic in ArcGIS Pro, you see the description not the code.  The function is [DomainName()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#domainname) and has the syntax `DomainName($feature, 'grade')` where the second parameter is the field name. To see the actual code value I would reduce the expression to `$feature.grade`.